# Swift hide navigation title but show its title as back button in next view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am using tab bar controller as main and following way-
  `UITabbarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UITableViewController` (with 5 tab bar & uncheck show navigation bar & made `UIView` with mail box image as button  then click ) -> `ViewController` (with 5 tab bar & without back button )

I want to get back button as first tab bar title name like < Home

Please let me know the programmatic or structure way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to hide titleView label

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the text from the back button. The simplest way is to set it as empty string, like this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "TEXT"
```